# NodeJS website uploaded to Heroku won't load, can't find dependencies for some reason

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, deployment, npm-install

Tried to upload my website to an Heroku server.
It's not my first time and I usefully do not encounter any problems. I have added a profcile.
This is the package.json:

```
    {
  "name": "exodia-coming-soon",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Coming Soon\r http://exodia.io",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.4",
    "path": "^0.12.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/Amirh24/exodia-landing.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/Amirh24/exodia-landing/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/Amirh24/exodia-landing#readme"
}
```

What matters is the dependencies and 
devDependencies part.

When I upload it to heroku and it wont load, the logs show:

```
2018-09-26T12:09:21.012703+00:00 app[web.1]: > exodia-coming-soon@1.0.0 start /app
2018-09-26T12:09:21.012705+00:00 app[web.1]: > nodemon server.js
2018-09-26T12:09:21.012706+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-09-26T12:09:21.107321+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:550
2018-09-26T12:09:21.107325+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2018-09-26T12:09:21.107326+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2018-09-26T12:09:21.107329+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '../lib/cli'
```

When I try to start without nodemon, just node server.js I get:

```
2018-09-26T11:49:07.146721+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2018-09-26T11:49:07.146723+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-09-26T11:49:07.257964+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:550
2018-09-26T11:49:07.257968+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2018-09-26T11:49:07.257969+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2018-09-26T11:49:07.257971+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-09-26T11:49:07.257973+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module './lib/express'
```

I have installed my 3 dependencies: express, path and nodemon a couple of times with both --save and -g variants. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Where is that error being thrown? It looks like you're trying to use files in a relative position, not `express` in `node_modules`. Does your project have a `lib` folder? Are you uploading it as well?

You can uninstall the global express with `npm uninstall -g express`. Delete your `node_modules` folder and start fresh with `npm install` and `npm start`. Does it run locally?